# React-Router useParams bring user data at multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

***I'm trying to get a images of specific user, and i'm using userId to get that data, so each users has their own images with nested object ,  when i click on user card i'm getting user detail that display with length of his images so if user has 1 image on his profile will get details one time if 2 images will get 2 deails two time and ......***

```
data.json
[
  {
    "creatorName": "Leo Penry",
    "creatorId": "leopenry",
    "location": "USA",
    "bio": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
    "creationsNum": "3",
    "collectionNum": "0",
    "avatar": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg",
    "creations": [
      {
        "id": "0",
        "img": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/22.jpg",
        "title": "Paradox",
        "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
        "owner": "Hakar",
        "ownerAvatar": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/3.jpg",
        "priceTez": 15,
        "priceUsd": 187,
        "edition": 1,
        "editions": 2,
        "collection": "My Collection"
      },
      {
        "id": "1",
        "img": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/4.jpg",
        "title": "Pop",
        "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
        "owner": "Hakar",
        "ownerAvatar": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/3.jpg",
        "priceTez": 2,
        "priceUsd": 12,
        "edition": 1,
        "editions": 1,
        "collection": "My Collection"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "img": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/8.jpg",
        "title": "Maistro",
        "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
        "owner": "Hakar",
        "ownerAvatar": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/3.jpg",
        "priceTez": 8,
        "priceUsd": 66,
        "edition": 1,
        "editions": 4,
        "collection": "My Collection"
      }
    ]
  }
]


UserPageWrapper.js


const UserPageWrapper = (props) => {
  const [artworks, setArtworks] = useState(props.artworks);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const { name } = useParams();
  // console.log('hey', useParams());

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    props.dispatch(loadArts());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.artworks.length > 0) {
      setArtworks(props.artworks);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [props.artworks]);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        artworks &&
        artworks
          .filter((art) => art.creatorId === name)

          .map((art) =>
            art.creations.map((item) => (
              <div key={item.id}>
                <UserPage
                  avatar={art.avatar}
                  creatorName={art.creatorName}
                  location={art.location}
                  collectionNum={art.collectionNum}
                  creationsNum={art.creationsNum}
                  bio={art.bio}
                />
              </div>
            ))
          )
      )}
    </>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  artworks: state.artworks,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserPageWrapper)

userPage.js

function UserPage({
  avatar,
  creatorId,
  creatorName,
  location,
  collectionNum,
  creationsNum,
  bio,
  img,
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <UserProfileWrapper>
        <UserLeftSide>
          <UserDetails>
            <UserWrapper>
              <img src={avatar} alt="avatar" />
              <UserNameWrapper>
                <h1>{creatorName}</h1>
                <h3>@{creatorId}</h3>
              </UserNameWrapper>
            </UserWrapper>
            <LocationWrapper>
              <LocationIcon /> <p>{location}</p>
            </LocationWrapper>
            <CCWrapper>
              <Collections>
                <p>COLLECTIONS</p>
                <h1>{collectionNum}</h1>
              </Collections>
              <Creations>
                <p>CREATIONS</p>
                <h1>{creationsNum}</h1>
              </Creations>
            </CCWrapper>
            <SocialLinkWrapper>
              <GlobalIcon />
              <TwitterIcon />
              <InstaIcon />
            </SocialLinkWrapper>
            <BioWrapper>
              <p>{bio}</p>
            </BioWrapper>
          </UserDetails>
        </UserLeftSide>

        <UserRightSide>
          <img src={img} alt="" />
        </UserRightSide>
      </UserProfileWrapper>
    </>
  );
}

export default UserPage;
```

this is result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyPPG.jpg

Comment: Hi, if I understand correctly, you only want to display the user information one time but you want to display all of their photos?

Comment: Hi,
yes that's right

Comment: Can you provide a link to the repo or paste the code to the UserPage component?

Comment: yes, just updated the post

Comment: Cool. What actually do you want to display just so I am clear? Do you have Discord so we can chat there and I help you with this?

Comment: fixed that, thanks!! i just created another component called userPageImages   since we have a nested array object so for each of them i create different map

Comment: yes please add me on discord @hakar_yusuf

Comment: Discord is asking me for your 4 digit tag

Comment: this is it #8354

Comment: Just add me because it's not working when I try with the username and number you gave me. @jevoncochran

Comment: same here , asking for digit code :)

Comment: That would be #5594

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are rendering a UserPage component for each creation. I believe what you want to do is render one UserPage component based on the name param. And then render all the users' art images by mapping over creations. So in this case, you would do the mapping inside the UserPage component.